# How do I implement a custom IFeatureDatasetExtension?

Tags: arcobjects, extensions, feature-dataset

**How can I implement IFeatureDatasetExtension and register it so that ArcGIS discovers and initializes it?**

In arcobjects, I see that Esri has a number of coclasses that implement [IFeatureDatasetExtension2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureDatasetExtension2_Interface/0025000002wq000000/).  Using Categories.exe, I see there is a COM category called "Esri Workspace Dataset Extensions".

[image]

I don't see anything on the FeatureDataset coclass that would let me register extensions, the closest thing is [IFeatureDatasetExtensionContainer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureDatasetExtensionContainer_Interface/0025000002ws000000/), but it only lets me access extensions that are already defined.  There is no `Add` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes in the `Esri Workspace Dataset Extension` component category do not seem to implement [IFeatureDatasetExtension2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureDatasetExtension2_Interface/0025000002wq000000/) (I checked the implemented interfaces in the documentation and with OLE Viewer). They are workspace extensions, implementing [IWorkspaceExtension](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000m91000000).

This category appears to identify those workspace extensions which are tied to specialized dataset types which live inside feature datasets. As these are part of the [esriDatasetType](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000042000000) enumeration (like `esriDTMosaicDataset`, `esriDTNetworkDataset`, `esriDTRepresentationClass`, `esriDTCadastralFabric`, `esriDTTerrain`), my impression is that the mechanism is not open for extensibility.